# How to join table in LINQ with aspnetusers and then create new object with results for ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

just want to know what I should be adding in the **select new block** to retrieve SQL query result.
I have a BlogViewModel, and two tables blog and users. I want to join the two tables get the result and then have this in a object I can pass to View.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
           
            List<BlogViewModel> blogs = _db.blog.ToList();  //add elements into blogs list   
            List<IdentityUserHelper> users = _db.Users.ToList(); //add elements into users

            var result = from b in blogs   //"blogs" is list
                         join u in users   //"users" is list
                         on b.userID equals u.Id into group1 //join tables blogs with aspnetusers
            select new    //below is object initliazer
            {
            //I want to join table with aspnetusers?? don't know what to put in here

                
            };

            var blogList = new List<BlogViewModel>();  //create list for blogs
            
            foreach (var test in result) //iterate through queryresult
            {
                blogList.Add(new BlogViewModel
                {
                    blogID = test.blogID,
                    blogContent = test.blogContent
                    userID = test.userID

                }
                );
```

```
    public class BlogViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int blogID { get; set; }

        public string title { get; set; }
        public string blogContent { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }

        public DateTime publishedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need foreach loop here. Try this

```
var model = from b in blogs   
                         join u in users   
                         on b.userID equals u.Id into bj 
                         from b in bj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new  BlogViewModel
                {
                    blogID = b.blogID,
                    blogContent = b.blogContent
                    userID = u.userID
                    author =u.Name
                }
            };
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select desired fields for the result with the desired aliases:

```
 var result = from b in blogs   
                 join u in users   
                 on b.userID equals u.Id into group1 //join tables blogs with aspnetusers
                             select new    //below is object initliazer
                             {
                                 blogID = b.blogID,  
                                 blogContent = b.blogContent,
                                 userID = b.userID,
                                 author = u.Name
    
                             };
```

also, you can `select new BlogViewModel` directly in the result instead of `select new` and you won't need using foreach in order to return list of BlogViewModel items.